# Videos play even when they are not called on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have several videos that are commanded to play when specific keys are pressed (each video has a specific key assigned). It works perfectly fine except that sometimes when a key (any key) is pressed for the first time since the page is opened all the videos play at the same time (when it should be just one). I think this happens when a key is pressed too soon after the page is opened. Maybe it's a loading problem.

Another smaller issue is that sometimes after a video finishes playing the last frame doesn't dissapear for the screen. It doesn't happen often and its not always the same videos.

I'm new to coding and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

HTML:

```
<body>
    
    <div> 
<a href="aboutpage.html">
<img id="about" src="videos/about.png" alt= "start"> </a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="letras">

<!--b1-->


        <video id="b1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/b1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--p1-->


        <video id="p1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/p1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--k1-->


        <video id="k1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/k1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--g1-->


        <video id="g1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/g1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--z1-->


        <video id="z1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/z1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--x1-->


        <video id="x1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/x1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
     <!--d1-->
    
     <video id="d1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/d1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
     <!--f1-->
    
     <video id="f1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/f1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--m1-->
    
     <video id="m1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/m1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--q1-->
    
     <video id="q1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/q1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--v1-->
    
     <video id="v1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/v1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--s1-->
    
     <video id="s1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/s1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--t1-->
    
     <video id="t1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/t1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--j1-->
    
     <video id="j1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/j1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--e1-->
    
     <video id="e1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/e1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>

    
    <!--i1-->
    
     <video id="i1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/i1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--y1-->
    
     <video id="y1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/y1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--a1-->
    
     <video id="a1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/a1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--u1-->
    
     <video id="u1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/u1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--w1-->
    
     <video id="w1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/W1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--h1-->
    
     <video id="h1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/h1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--r1-->
    
     <video id="r1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/r1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
        
        <!--o1-->
    
     <video id="o1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/o1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
        
        <!--c1-->
    
     <video id="c1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/c1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
        
        <!--l1-->
    
     <video id="l1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/l1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
        
        <!--n1-->
    
     <video id="n1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/n1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    

        </div>
    
    
<script src="animations.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

JAVA:

```
var videos = {
    'b': document.getElementById('b1'),
    'p': document.getElementById('p1'),
    'k': document.getElementById('k1'),
    'g': document.getElementById('g1'),
    'z': document.getElementById('z1'),
    'x': document.getElementById('x1'),
    'd': document.getElementById('d1'),
    'f': document.getElementById('f1'),
    'm': document.getElementById('m1'),
    'q': document.getElementById('q1'),
    'v': document.getElementById('v1'),
    's': document.getElementById('s1'),
    't': document.getElementById('t1'),
    'j': document.getElementById('j1'),
    'e': document.getElementById('e1'),
    'i': document.getElementById('i1'),
    'y': document.getElementById('y1'),
    'a': document.getElementById('a1'),
    'u': document.getElementById('u1'),
    'w': document.getElementById('w1'),
    'h': document.getElementById('h1'),
    'r': document.getElementById('r1'),
    'o': document.getElementById('o1'),
    'c': document.getElementById('c1'),
    'l': document.getElementById('l1'),
    'n': document.getElementById('n1'),
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    let video = videos[e.key];
    if (video) {
        video.play();
        video.currentTime = 0;
        
        
        
    }   
});
```

Comment: autoplay="true"

Comment: You're telling the video's to play whenever they can with the `autoplay` attribute. Browser are pretty strict about video's playing automatically and sometimes need user input before playing at all. That could be the cause of all video's playing at once. Off-topic: I noticed you're selecting all video's individually. But you could simplify this tremendously by selecting all video's and loop over them to create your `videos` object.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you for the information. Do you know any way I can solve this? (Thank you about the off-topic tip!)

Comment: Try to remove the attribute.